# Python 3 and pandas parsing a long date format in Excel

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use python and pandas to select specific dates from an excel spreadsheet. However, the code below always returns: Empty DataFrame

It does show correct columns and I can select other columns. Am I doing anything wrong here? I suspect the date format in the excel spreadsheet is the problem ex. 'Saturday, August 12, 2023'.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import datetime
import os

import pandas as pd
from pandasql import sqldf


# Load Excel file into DataFrame and use the second row as the column names
url = "~/Master Broadcast Schedule.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name='2023', header=1)

# Convert "Air date" column to datetime format
df['Air date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Air date'], format="%A, %B %d, %Y")

# Define SQL query to select data for a specific date

date_str = "2023-05-01" # replace with your desired date
date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
query = """
    SELECT *
    FROM df
    WHERE "Air date" = '{}'
""".format(date_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

# Execute SQL query on DataFrame
result = sqldf(query)

# Print query result
print(result)
```

I was expecting to get the row of the date 2023-05-01.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `print(df.head().to_dict())` please?

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are correctly converted with `pd.to_datetime`, you can simply use:

```
# Load Excel file into DataFrame and use the second row as the column names
url = "~/Master Broadcast Schedule.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name='2023', header=1)

# Convert "Air date" column to datetime format
df['Air date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Air date'], format="%A, %B %d, %Y")

# HERE
result = df[df['Air date'] == '2023-05-01']
```

Output:

```
>>> result
    Air date
1 2023-05-01
```

Input data:

```
>>> df
                    Air date
0  Saturday, August 12, 2023
1        Monday, May 1, 2023
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I couldn't get pandasql to work so I just am using something even simpler, just pandas. Still interested in an SQL solution if anyone can come up with one. Couple notable items: the header=1 is important, this specifies which column you want to start your column names. Adjust as needed. Sometimes there's a header column above it that people use to name their Excel sheet. Row 0 = first column Row 1 = second column. Also note the "print(result.to_string(index=False, header=False))" which gives you a super clean output with no additional text. Adjust as needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import datetime
import pandas as pd

#Load Excel file into DataFrame and use the second row as the column names
url = "~/Master Broadcast Schedule.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name='2023', header=1)

# Convert "Air date" column to datetime format
df['Air date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Air date'], format="%A, %B %d, %Y")

# Define date to filter
date_to_find = pd.to_datetime('8/14/2023', format='%m/%d/%Y')

# Filter DataFrame by date
result = df.loc[df['Air date'] == date_to_find, ['Title', 'Program#']]
# Example 1) result = df.loc[df['Air date'] == date_to_find, ['Air time', 'Program name']]

print(result.to_string(index=False, header=False))
```